# Test Driven Development for Sequelize models

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tdd, sequelize.js

I am working on a node.js project that uses Sequelize as it's ORM and Postgres as the database. Our Technical Lead requires us to write tests for the models. How do I do that? I have scoured the web but not found how?

How can I write tests for Sequelize models with Mocha?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sequelize-test-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-test-helpers). It's a collection of utilities to help with unit-testing Sequelize models and code that needs those models.